# If $f_n \to f$ a.e and $f_n\to g$ in measure, then $f=g$ a.e

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

As in the title i am trying to show that the two modes of convergence agree. My idea was as follows and was wondering if it is possible to salvage it. Let $A_\epsilon=\{x | |f(x)-g(x)|>\epsilon\}$ Then 
$A_\epsilon \subseteq \{x| |f_n-f|>\epsilon/2\}\cup \{x| |f_n-g|>\epsilon/2\}$ Since $f_n \to g$ in measure we get that $\mu(A_\epsilon)<\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(\{x| |f_n-f|>\epsilon/2\})$. But I get stuck here, i cannot claim that the limit is 0, as that would imply that $f_n \to f$ in measure. Is this salvagable? I found the proof of the proposition here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/ I am just trying to see if my proof can be saved.

Comment: Can you use a $|f-g|\le |f_n-f| + |f_n-g|$ argument?

Comment: @JVV That is exactly what i am using when claiming that $A_\epsilon$  is a subset of the two sets.

Comment: The standard way is to prove that there is  subsequence of $(f_n)$ converging a.e. to $g$. I don't think this proof can be simplified.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That is a very simple argument i overlooked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

But it's true that $f_n\to f$ a.e. implies $f_n\to f$ in measure, provided the space $X$ on which everything is defined has finite measure. If that's the case, just keep going. If the space is $\sigma$-finite, consider an increasing collection of sets of measure $n$ whose union is $X$.